# Light business jets - how many are sold each year?

Tags: private-jets

This AOPA article  says

https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2018/october/16/hondajets-get-performance-upgrades

> The company is delivering four to five aircraft a month from its Greensboro, North Carolina, factory, the CEO said. In 2017 and the first half of 2018, the HondaJet was the most delivered light jet in the market. All in all, 92 HondaJets are in service with a 99.7-percent dispatch rate, Fujino explained.

So that's 48 to 60 a year.  What other light jets are available for purchase?

Comment: And only $4M USD for a 2016 model that was only flown 120 times (180 Flight Hours Since New. 120 Landings Since New.)  Just need to win the lottery now!  https://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/list/manufacturer/honda/model/hondajet

Comment: What do you qualify as a "business jet" vs a personal jet like the Cirrus SF50?

Comment: Apparently there are several small jets, most are twins and then the single engine SF50, half the price of the others. https://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/g21098242/best-light-jet-airplanes/  Now I just need those powerball numbers (lottery) to turn out my way ...

Answer (score 1):

For the most recent data available, which is in 2017, GAMA reports that 676 business jets sold worldwide. You can see a breakdown by manufacturer [here](https://www.sherpareport.com/aircraft/sales-business-jets-2017.html).

Unfortunately, not all manufacturers detail the models sold. Light business jets typically sell in higher volume, due to their lower cost point. A rough estimate of 60% of sales being light jets would give a rough number of ~405 light business jets sold in 2017. There is no way to ensure this is accurate, but it should give you a ballpark number.

Comment: Interestingly enough, a personal jet like the Cirrus SF50 qualifies as a "Very Light Business Jet", which is typically lumped into the Light section. Only 22 were sold in 2017, so that's not a major factor.

Answer (score 0):

GAMA  - General Aviation Manufacturers Assoc. - publishes detailed reports but category and type:

https://privatejetcardcomparisons.com/2020/02/21/private-jet-deliveries-see-big-gains-in-2019/
[image]

Comment: It's essential to include snippets (properly attributed) because links die or get changed, then your answer becomes meaningless gibberish. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn about the differences between this Q&A board and a regular "discussion" forum and the standards expected when answering.